# How to run dependant query in PostgreSQL transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql

I an postgres transaction I want to insert 1 record each to two tables say A & B,
B has a foreign key to the record inserted to A in the same transaction.

How do I refer the inserted record here so that I can insert on table B

Comment: Start transaction, insert into A and remember new record id, then use it to insert into B, commit transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the actual table structure, so I have to make things up, but a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) can be used to do that in one statement

```
with new_a_row as (
  insert into a (col1, col2, col3) 
  values ('one', 'two', 42)
  returning id --<<< this is the generated primary key of the table A
)
insert into b (b_col_one, b_col_two, fk_col_to_a)
select 100, 'something', id
from new_a_row;
```

Alternatively use `lastval()` and do this in two statements

```
begin;
insert into a (col1, col2, col3) 
values ('one', 'two', 42);

insert into b (b_col_one, b_col_two, fk_col_to_a)
values (100, 'something', lastval());
commit;
```

The first solution will work with any "generation strategy" not only `identity` or `serial` columns but also if you e.g. use `gen_random_uuuid()` as a default value.

The second solution requires an `identity` or the old `serial` type column.

Comment: in the first code is it `select 100,...` or `values ( 100...)`

Comment: It's `values` in the first insert, but you need to use `select ` in the second part to get the generated value that is returned by the previous insert