# Error in using with statement with PostgreSQL insert query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use a `with` clause with postgres insert statement

```sql
with inserted_record as (insert into person_age(person_name, years_old) values ('asnim', 21) returning *);
```

However, it errors out like

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
  Position: 108
```

If i run it with without the the `with` clause it works

```sql
insert into person_age(person_name, years_old) values ('asnim', 21) returning *;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need some statement _after_ the WITH. As written your WITH statement makes no sense

Comment: You mean, the variable declared should be used below the first statement.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's different that you want to happen with the `with` clause that doesn't happen in normal insert? Cause yeah, normal insert works, there doesn't appear to be a need for anything more complex.

Comment: @Deltharis, I was trying to use row in `inserted_record` and use its id as foreign key in another table.

Comment: Then write the full query you're trying to run. The With statment looks mostly correct, it's just that you don't do anywithing with `inserted_record` yet, and with statement can't exist by itself like @a_horse_with_no_name said.

Comment: I showed you the correct and full syntax for that in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68464691/330315) to your previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE (`WITH` clause) is part of an SQL statement and cannot stand on its own. PostgreSQL complains about an error at the end of the statement, because it expects a following `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

In a way, a CTE is like a view defined only for a single statement. You cannot define a CTE and then use it with several statements; for that, you could define a temporary view in the `pg_temp` schema.